# RAD Studio, lock item position in design mode

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I've searched the documentation for this, and I feel kind of silly asking since this should seem common sense.
It's imperative to lock VCL controls when using the GUI designer, because there is no undo, and it's so easy to accidentally move something and the stupid auto-align ruins the placement of something.

**I've done it before, but I cannot find where the option is to *lock* elements in design mode.**

Anybody know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such option built in to the Form Designer itself to lock the position of controls.  You must have been using a third-party extension add-on to control that.

Comment: Or maybe I'm remembering an older version or another IDE. Either way that's a really stupid design flaw.